# Disable a JComboBox based off the item of another ComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

So here is what I am trying to do. If a user selects an item in `JComboBox1`, I want to be able to disable `JComboBox2`. But only if they select `"Unavailable"`. I have read stuff about `action listeners` and so forth, but is there just a way for me to use like an if statement:
Here is what I was thinking:

```
if (jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Unavailable") == true) {
        jComboBox2.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That would certainly work, but you would have to call that piece of code periodically. Much better would be to use an ActionListener - it will definitely help you in the future. You have to create a class which implements the ActionListener, such as

```
//This class should be a private class inside the class which holds the JComboBoxes.
private class DisableActionListener implements ActionListener { 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        if (cb.getSelectedItem().equals("Unavailable")) {
            jComboBox2.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

For this to work, you have to attach the ActionListener to the first JComboBox - the ActionListener is no good by itself! To do this, use the addActionListener() method on the JComboBox, adding an instance of this newly created class.

Now, to dissect the code:

```
private class DisableActionListener implements ActionListener
```

Here, we create a class which *implements* the ActionListener interface. With this, we are creating our own model of an ActionListener. When you implement an interface, you have to override all of the interface's methods, so we have to override the standard actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method on the interface. This method is what will be called whenever you select or deselect an item(an ActionEvent will be dispatched); therefore, you have to put the logic of what you want to happen inside this method.

```
JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
```

Every ActionEvent which causes the actionPerformed() method to be called will contain extra data. One of the pieces of the data is the source of the ActionEvent - what made this action happen? In this case, we know that the source is a JComboBox since we only attached the ActionListener to the JComboBox, so we can cast the source of the ActionEvent, which is an Object, to the JComboBox which sent the event.

The rest is the if logic you wrote yourself, with the syntax error fixed:

You wrote

```
(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().equals("Unavailable") == true),
```

but the equals() method on the String already returns true, so the (== true) part is an unneeded redundancy. In your case, you basically get (true == true).

Anyway, hope this helps!